# How do I create multiple windows in different classes than the main function in C++ with Win32

Tags: c++, class, winapi, program-entry-point

How do I create multiple windows in different classes than the WinMain function in C++ with Win32?

What I am trying to do:

My Source Files:

- FileThatContainsMainFunction.cpp
- Window1.cpp
- Window2.cpp

In the Main Function I would like to make two objects (one for Window1 and one or Window2) that create Win32 Windows in their constuctors.
eg:

```
Window1 w1;
Window2 w2;
```

Note: This question is directed towards C++ classes, not Win32 Classes.

Comment: And how would you normally create a window? I find it unclear from your question exactly what you're having trouble with (i.e. if you can create one window, why is creating two a problem)?

Comment: Introduce yourself to the Windows API. Start with Charles Petzold's [Programming Windows®](http://www.amazon.com/Programming-Windows%C2%AE-Edition-Developer-Reference/dp/157231995X). The [tag:class] tag is dubios. The Windows API is purely exposed through a flat C interface.

Comment: @IInspectable: I suspect "classes" in the question refers to window classes. I.e. the kind you represent with a `WNDCLASS`/`WNDCLASSEX`.

Comment: @Michael: Unfortunately, this is not something the OP is aware of yet. This really is about C++ classes, with constructors and all that. Wrapping native windows in C++ classes is not something a beginner will succeed with.

Comment: @Michael: The OP mentions "constructors", so clearly the use of "classes" refers to C++ classes, not window classes. `Window1` is a C++ class that creates a window of one window class, and `Window2` is a C++ class that creates a window of a different window class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works pretty much the way you described in your question:

Window1.h

```
#ifndef Window1H

#include <windows.h>

class Window1
{
private:
    HWND hWnd;
public:
    Window1();
    ~Window1();
};

#endif
```

Window1.cpp

```
#include "Window1.h"

Window1::Window1()
{
    // register and create window as needed
    hWnd = CreateWindowEx(...);
}

Window1::~Window1()
{
    DestroyWindow(hWnd);
}
```

Window2.h

```
#ifndef Window2H

#include <windows.h>

class Window2
{
private:
    HWND hWnd;
public:
    Window2();
    ~Window2();
};

#endif
```

Window2.cpp

```
#include "Window2.h"

Window2::Window2()
{
    // register and create window as needed
    hWnd = CreateWindowEx(...);
}

Window2::~Window2()
{
    DestroyWindow(hWnd);
}
```

FileThatContainsMainFunction.cpp

```
#include "Window1.h"
#include "Window2.h"

int CALLBACK WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{
    Window1 w1;
    Window2 w2;
    //...
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I don't see why you were need two different classes `Window1` and `Window2`  just create two Window1 classes

Comment: And if the OP needs to create two windows using different window classes?  Different parameters to `RegisterClass/Ex()`? How would you propose doing that in a single class without muddying up its interface?

Comment: Fair point. It would be much more complex to do it another way. (Perfect forwarding would be messy, options system would be worse. )

Answer (score -1):

Everything is possible with the Win API and some C++. But it is not that easy: before creating a window, its WNDCLASS must be registered. As C++ is not very kind with static initialization, you will have to do it in your main before creating any window. After that, you will be able to create your windows with the solution of @RemyLebeau.

If you want to make use of C++ classes to wrap a WNDCLASS, you will need a static function for the WndProc, and store a pointer to the C++ object through `SetWindowsLong` in the Windows itself. And the only place to do it safely is in the `WM_CREATE` or `WM_NCCREATE` notification message. But once this is done, you can simply create many windows in that class, and you will be able to access the c++ object form the (static) WndProc.

As WinAPI is not specially simple nor C++ friendly, my advice would be:

- first create your windows directly using the API and forget C++ classes 
  for the moment
- once this works, refactor your application but identifying classes and objects, and optionally use the WM_CREATE trick to allow the WndProc to access directly to the c++ objects
- if you want to go further, change the WndProc into a wrapper that just looks for the proper C++ object all calls a non static method on it.

You could look the [WTL](http://wtl.sourceforge.net/) as an example of using C++ above the C Windows API, but unfortunately the documentation is quite poor.

Comment: Another common way to set up a C++ object pointer is to use a CBT hook. This way you can pass the very first message to a class member function, without knowing, which one it is (`WM_NCCREATE` may not be it), and without any conditionals in the static window procedure. This is how MFC implements ist plumbing.